# backbone collections - how to filter a collection with other collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have two collections:

- **Collection `A`** with `model1`, `model2`, `model3`, `model4`.
- **Collection `B`** with `model2`, `model3`.

For example:

```
var model1 = new models.ExModel({id: "1", name: "model1"});
var model2 = new models.ExModel({id: "2", name: "model2"});
var model3 = new models.ExModel({id: "3", name: "model3"});
var model4 = new models.ExModel({id: "4", name: "model4"});

var A = new collections.ExCol([ model1, model2, model3, model4 ]);
var B = new collections.ExCol([ model2, model3 ]);
```

I want to get an array of models of `A` that are not contained in `B`. In example, I want to get an array with `model1` and `model4`. How Can I do this in the most efficient?

I have thought two options to do this, but I don't know if is the best way to do it. I think Option1 is more efficient than Option2.

Option1:

```
var idsB = B.pluck("id");
var result = A.filter( function(m) { return idsB.indexOf(m.id) === -1; } );
```

Option2:

```
var result = A.filter( function(m) { return !B.contains(m); });
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/VH3HU/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use the underscore method `_.difference`. http://underscorejs.org/#difference

```
var results = _.difference(A.models, B.models);
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I like this option. I hadn't seen this method. I hope that this is efficient.

Comment: +1. A good thing to know is that this works only when the models are the *same* Model instance in two collections. If they're two different instances, even if all their properties are equal, it won't.